# How can I print Jquery output to a field that saves on form submission?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, forms

I'm using the following code to output the wordcount of an array, separated by ", " (comma and a space) and count the amount of words:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('#field_d9kag').change(function(){
  var s = this.value;
  s = s.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/gi,"");
  s = s.replace(/[ ]{2,}/gi," ");
  s = s.replace(/\n /,"\n");
 document.getElementById("frm_field_104_container").innerHTML = (s.split(', ').length);
});
});
```

The `('#field_d9kag')` just relates to another field that holds the array. What the script sees is, for example:

> One, Two, Three

This actually works great and gives the correct wordcount number. Although the number shows, it can't actually be used in the way needed. My aim is to place it in the field `("frm_field_104_container")` and save it as a form entry, but it currently can't be saved to the database on form submission by this method. Instead it acts more as document.write or console.log. Great for seeing what's what, but not fit for the pupose needed.

Can anyone point me in the direction of how to make the count a saveable entry/input within a form field?

Comment: html is never submitted on form submit.  input values are.  So if you want to send that value on a normal form submit, you have to put it in the value of an input/textarea/etc.  Some normal form field.

Comment: provide a codepen or jsfiddle working example for quick solution

Comment: @MrKhan Thank you, working link provided in original post now

Comment: @Taplar Thank you, that actually makes sence. Can I target the input with an id? I think I've seen it done before with for="something" or name="something"

Comment: I need to be able to see the code bro. A working example without code wont do any good.

Comment: Sure.  `<input type="hidden" id="passAlong">` could be targeted with `$('#passAlong').val('my new value')`

Comment: @Taplar You my friend are a saviour! Thank you! I'm using a form plugin on Wordpress so it wasn't as simple as changing my own code. After further inspection, I found an ID had been dynamically created for the input of that field so using your `$('#passAlong').val('my new value')` with the correct ID sorted it out.

Many thanks, I'd been scrathing my head for two days now!! :)

Comment: Awesome!  Glad you figured it out.  Hope that puts a happy cap on your friday evening, :)

Comment: @MrKhan Thank you for your input. The issue has been resolved with Taplars suggestion

Comment: @Taplar It seriously has! Thanks again!